# Hows does one account for the speed of light delay in field equations?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

Suppose I have a simple time varying classical field $\vec{f}$.

The force of the field on an object with a charge $X$ at a position $S$ is:

$ \vec{F_f}\left( t \right) = X \vec{f}\left( t \right) $

And the strength of a field around the charge $X$ for any field $\vec{f}$ is:

$ \vec{f}\left( t \right) = \frac{\vec{F_f}\left( t \right)}{X} $

This field is the summation of many little forces $\vec{F_{fi}}$:

$ \vec{f}\left( t \right) = \frac{\sum{ \vec{F_{fi}}\left( t  \right)}}{X}  $

With no speed of light delay the field $\vec{f}$ is the summation of
forces from many different charges $x$ at positions $\vec{s}$ affected by some constant $a$.

$ \vec{f}\left( t \right) = \sum{ \frac{a x_i}{|\vec{S} - \vec{s_{i}} |}^2 \hat{\left( \vec{S} - \vec{s_{i}} \right)} } $
$ \vec{f}\left( t \right) = a \sum{ \frac{x_i}{{|\vec{S} - \vec{s_{i}} |}^2} \hat{\left( \vec{S} - \vec{s_{i}} \right)} }$

This can all be restated using integration in terms of integrating for
every point $\vec{s}$ in a volume $C$ a quantity with respect to the
infinitesimal volume $|dC| = |\left\{\vec{s}\right\}|$ of the set $dC =\left\{ \vec{s}
\right\}$ consisting of the single point $\vec{s}$.

$ \vec{f}\left( t \right) = \frac{\int _{\vec{s} \in C} \vec{F_{f}}\left( t, \vec{s} \right) \, |dC|}{X}  $

$ \vec{f}\left( t \right) = a \int _{\vec{s} \in C} \frac{x\left(\vec{s}\right)}{{|\vec{S} - \vec{s}|}^2} \hat{\left( \vec{S} - \vec{s} \right)} \, |dC|$

But how does one modify these classical field equations to account for a speed of light (or slower) delay for the effects of charges to reach other charges?

Comment: The equations you start with are only valid for static distributions of charges.  If the charges are moving, you have to take into account the fact that the field at $S$ *now* was sourced at some different location at some time in the past.  That's about all I can say because   I am having difficulty understanding your notation.  Your first equation makes no mention of $S$, for example.

Comment: @garyp That's basically my question. How do I make the equations valid for moving charges?

Comment: The term you want to look up is 'retarded/advanced potential'. Basically, it's exactly the same as what you already have, but the positions of the charges are evaluated at the 'retarded time', i.e. the time accounting for light propagation delay.

Comment: @KevinZhou I'm confused. In order to calculate the retarded time I need to know the retarded position but in order to calculate the retarded position I need to know the retarded time?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the solution may not be unique, but it is! You can think about it this way: the retarded position is where you would _see_ the charge. This uniquely determines both.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating this is based on the concept of retarded time and retarded variables.

The retarded time is:

$ t_r = t - \frac{|\vec{S} - \vec{s}|}{c} $

The retarded field would then be:

$ \vec{f} \left( t \right) = a \int _{\vec{s} \in C} \frac{x\left(\vec{s}, t_r \right)}{{|\vec{S} - \vec{s}|}^2} \hat{\left( \vec{S} - \vec{s} \right)} \, |dC| $

Or possibly:

$ \vec{f} \left( t \right) = a \int _{\vec{s} \in C} \frac{x\left(\vec{s}\right) - \int_{t_r}^t{\frac{d x \left(\vec{s}\right)}{dt} \, dt}}{{|\vec{S} - \vec{s} |}^2} \hat{\left( \vec{S} - \vec{s} \right)} \, |dC| $